# How to get user id and post id of photos, videos and posts from the Facebook Url

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the page id and post id from the facebook url using the Facebook graph API ?

For video -
facebook.com/sampleTestPage/videos/vb.77018700065049/770205000129979/?type=2&theater
For photo -
facebook.com/sampleTestPage/photos/a.770200009796850.1070001826.770187000465049/770308000119648/?type=3&theater

I can get user id using - https://graph.facebook.com/sampleTestPage?access_token={my_access_token}

But what about the post id of the video. I know the id is 770205000129979. But I don't know if parsing the URL to get the id (for photos or videos or normal posts) is the correct way to do it ?

There could be (I'm not sure if there are) multiple variations in the URL. So parsing the url would be difficult if there are a lot of variations. So is there like a much better way in the graph API to get the user id and post id from the URL ?

Like just the URL gives us the user id and post id in that url. I went through a lot of documentation and questions here but couldn't find anything of help. What would be the better of doing this ?

Edit - Since knowing the user id and post id is not possible using any APIs (as CBroe mentioned in the comments). What could be a better way to get the user id and post id of all the posts (videos, photos, normal posts) from a user's page. Basically i need to get the insights of all the posts a user has submitted.

(they have authenticated us to read insights and we have their access_token)

So what I am trying to do is something like this - 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/userId_postId/insights/post_impressions_unique?access_token={users_access_token}

But i would need to know exactly what the userId and postId is from the postUrl that they submit.

Comment: There is no way to get this via API. And yes, the URLs can have multiple different formats, depending where exactly they are taken from. // Why does your app need to deal with such URLs fed in from the outside, what is the actual purpose here?

Comment: The purpose is to let the user add any posts from his Facebook page. And to get insights of all such posts submitted by the users. (all the users have authenticated our app to read insights). So i need to get the user id and post id for all (video, photo or normal posts) posts coming from their page. Is there like a pattern or something that might be useful for me to get those from the user's page posts.

Comment: In that case it would be better if you got the posts via API in the first place - then you don’t have to deal with varying URL syntax, but get the IDs you need directly. Build a simple interface that reads the feed from the user’s page, and let them select the posts they want to add from there.

Comment: Yes that would have been much easier. But that's the problem. The whole proccess needs to be automated. All the users submit their posts. And we get data for all those posts. And we only need to do it for those users only who need it done and for only those posts that they submit, so not for all of them. Only the ones they submit. I wonder what to do now!

Comment: But the part of the users submitting those posts is not automated, is it?

Comment: no its not. they submit it once. and then we get their insights for every month since they submitted.

Comment: Well what is the problem then? You build the interface for the user to select the posts the want to submit to your system ... and then submit the selected post ids to your system.

Comment: The user submitting posts is not (loggedIn via facebook currently on our APP). He authenticated just once, thats why we get their access_token only. Now to do that i'll have to have the current users facebook access_token always once he's on our app, which we are only storing in the database right now. So that will require a huge amount of changes to how our system currently is. Also if we do that, the user can have many pages and hundreds or even more posts on his pages.

Comment: So even building the interface so that user can select for the posts he wants across all his pages and posts will be quite difficult too. I know this seems like complicated. But there's isn't an easy solution to this i guess.